# Removing the duplication in a JSON schema that uses oneOf (v4 or v5)

Tags: json, validation, schema, jsonschema

I have a set of 2 properties that are always optional, but should only be allowed to be present if the value of another (always required) boolean property is true.

The properties which are always optional, but not always allowed are named: `max_recurrences` and `recurrence_arguments`. The boolean property whose value of `true` that they depend on is named: `recurring`.

I've come up with the schema below, which I think works, but I'm duplicating all of the other properties in each item of the `oneOf` array. I'm looking for a way to avoid this duplication.

```
{
  "id": "plan_schedule",
  "type": "object",
  "oneOf": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "start_date": {
          "type": "string",
          "format": "date-time"
        },
        "end_date": {
          "type": "string",
          "format": "date-time"
        },
        "trigger": {
          "$ref": "re_non_empty_string"
        },
        "arguments": {
          "type": "object",
          "minProperties": 1
        },
        "recurring": {
          "type": "boolean",
          "enum": [true],
        },
        "max_recurrences": {
          "type": "integer",
          "minimum": 1
        },
        "recurrence_arguments": {
          "type": "object",
          "minProperties": 1
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "properties": {
        "start_date": {
          "type": "string",
          "format": "date-time"
        },
        "end_date": {
          "type": "string",
          "format": "date-time"
        },
        "trigger": {
          "$ref": "re_non_empty_string"
        },
        "arguments": {
          "type": "object",
          "minProperties": 1
        },
        "recurring": {
          "type": "boolean",
          "enum": [false],
        },
      }
    }
  ],
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "required": ["start_date", "trigger", "recurring"]
}
```

Can anyone help me out? I'd like to use v4, but I'm open to using v5 if it helps.

To clarify further, I'm hoping to only have to list the properties: `start_date`, `end_date`, `trigger` and `arguments` one time in the entire schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON Schema draft-04:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "recurring": {
      "type": "boolean"
    }
    // all other properties
  }
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "required": ["start_date", "trigger", "recurring"]
  "anyOf": [
    {
      "properties": { "recurring": { "enum": [true] } }
    },
    {
      "properties": { "recurring": { "enum": [false] } },
      "not": {
        "anyOf": [
          { "required": ["max_recurrences"] },
          { "required": ["recurrence_arguments"] }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

If you use Ajv (I assume so because v5 is the concept not used anywhere else) you can simplify the above using custom keywords "if/then/else" and "prohibited" that are proposed for draft-07 and have some support - they are defined in [ajv-keywords](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv-keywords). "anyOf" can be replaced with:

```
"if": { "properties": { "recurring": { "enum": [false] } } },
"then": { "prohibited": ["max_recurrences", "recurrence_arguments"] }
```

EDIT:

Actually, it can be done even simpler with "dependencies" keyword without any custom keywords. Instead of "anyOf":

```
"dependencies": {
  "max_recurrences": { "$ref": "#recurring" },
  "recurrence_arguments": { "$ref": "#recurring" }
},
"definitions": {
  "recurring": {
    "id": "#recurring",
    "properties": {
      "recurring": { "enum": [true] }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like this schema is deciding whether or not `recurrence_arguments` and `max_recurrences` should be **required** based on the value of `recurring`. That's not actually what I'm looking for. The fields should never be required, but should not be allowed if `recurring` is not `true`.

Comment: which option do you mean?

Comment: Your edit actually looks like it does what I want, but the top 2 look like they make the fields required if `recurring` is true. Am I mistaken?

Comment: Yes, edited, not required any more. The last is the best probably. But the second is the shortest and easier to read :)

Comment: Also replaced oneOf with anyOf - it's always better unless you need exactly oneOf

Comment: I re-read the EDIT you made, properties **max_recurrences**, **recurrence_arguments** may be present if recurring is true. Is it correct?