# How to write json schema to enforce conditional existence of other properties?

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

Schema should validate following json objects and should not allow any additional property.

```
{
  "id": "11111111111111111111111111111111",
  "status": "employed",
  "company_name": "Google"
}

{
  "id": "00000000000000000000000000000000",
  "status": "unemployed"
}
```

Schema draft v4:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties":false,
  "required": [
    "status",
    "id"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "status": {
      "type": "string",
      "enum":["unemployed", "employed"]
    },
    "company_name": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "company_name": {
      "properties": {
        "status": {
          "enum": [
            "employed"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This schema looks right but it does not invalidates following json object.

```
{
  "id": "00000000000000000000000000000001",
  "status": "employed"
}
```

It should be invalid because the "status" is "employed" but the required property "company_name" not provided.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41837518/removing-the-duplication-in-a-json-schema-that-uses-oneof-v4-or-v5/41838321?noredirect=1#comment70862053_41838321

Comment: @esp Its not clear over there.. Will you please elaborate. As per my observation: I'm using the last one(the best one) :)  Is there something I'm missing

Comment: @esp I have added an answer. Please add another answer to **how to do this using dependencies.**

Comment: I don't think it's possible. It's either anyOf or conditional

Answer (score 1):

This is possible using [anyOf](https://github.com/json-schema/json-schema/wiki/anyOf,-allOf,-oneOf,-not#anyof)  but not sure how to do it using [dependencies](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#rfc.section.5.19).

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "required": [
    "status",
    "id"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "status": {
      "type": "string",
      "enum": [
        "unemployed",
        "employed"
      ]
    },
    "company_name": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "anyOf": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "status": {
          "enum": [
            "employed"
          ]
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "company_name"
      ]
    },
    {
      "properties": {
        "status": {
          "enum": [
            "unemployed"
          ]
        }
      },
      "not": {
        "required": [
          "company_name"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks to [@esp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1816503/esp).